# __consumer_offsets : Conceptual Understanding

Tags: apache-kafka, offset, producer-consumer

I could not find there is no dedicated official documentation to explain this __consumer_offsets topic. Could you please help me understand on following question.

```
./kafka-simple-consumer-shell.sh --topic __consumer_offsets \
--partition 49 \
--broker-list localhost:9092 \
--formatter "kafka.server.OffsetManager\$OffsetsMessageFormatter"

testGroup,testTopic-development,0]::OffsetAndMetadata[11,NO_METADATA,1478243992053]
[testGroup,testTopic-development,0]::OffsetAndMetadata[12,NO_METADATA,1478243992086]
[testGroup,testTopic-development,0]::OffsetAndMetadata[13,NO_METADATA,1478243992096]
[testGroup,testTopic-development,0]::OffsetAndMetadata[14,NO_METADATA,1478243992110]
```

- what is Metadata value in this context with respective of this special topic?
- How this value will be get update frequently?
- NO_METADATA - if no Metadata means , this value is not valid one ?

Answer (score 0):

Since `kafka 0.9`, it’s not `zookeeper` anymore that store the information about what the offsets were consumed by each groupid on a topic by partition.

Kafka now store this information on a topic called `__consumer_offsets`

`Metadata` describes the currently available brokers, their host and port information, and gives information about which broker hosts which partitions.

The `NO_METADATA` is default behaviour in this situation.